# Is there a Zohar Yomi?

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar

I know about the Daf Yomi and Rambam Yomi learning schedules. Is there an active organization of a Zohar Yomi learning schedule though? Does someone know?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

There is a series of seforim called Chok L'Yisrael which creates a daily learning program including - tanach, mishnah, halacha and kabbalah. The Kabbalah section is from the Zohar.

For example see the Bereishis edition [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/43175) and also refer to the Chabad website which also presents a daily audio study of the zohar based on the divisions laid out in Chok L'Yisrael - [here](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1272146/jewish/Daily-Zohar-Study.htm)